# SAS - How to filter data?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I would appreciate if you could help me with this problem. I have the following data describing a relation between two individuals belonging to a group and a sub group:

```
Group ID | SubG ID | Ind1 ID | Rel 1 | Ind2 ID | Rel 2 |
        2        28         3       F         2       B
        2        28         2       F         1       B
        2        28         2       B        51       0
        2        29         1       R        42       0
        2        29         1       F        68       0
        3        30         1       F         2       L
        4        31         1       B         2       F
        4        31         1       F        44       0
```

I would like to get a database containing all individuals (Ind1 and Ind2) that belong to the same Group ID and same SubG ID, and that have only one relation=F, either as Ind1 ID or Ind2 ID. The database that I expect looks like:

```
Group ID | SubG ID | Ind | 
        2        28     3
        3        30     1
        4        31     2
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!
Manuel

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking for here. In each record, do the Group ID and SubG ID columns correspond to Ind1, Ind2 or both? What do you mean by 'all individuals that belong to the same Group ID and SubG ID? Also, your example output shows 3 individuals from 3 different groups and subgroup, which appears to contradict this requirement.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  You should make an effort and post the code that you have tried so we can guide you to an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert firstly the initial dataset into "long" form so that only one individual was in each row. Then it's pretty easy to select those that have only relation F within subgroup:

```
data have;
    input GroupID SubGID Ind1ID Rel1 $ Ind2ID Rel2 $;
    datalines;
2 28 3 F 2 B
2 28 2 F 1 B
2 28 2 B 51 0
2 29 1 R 42 0
2 29 1 F 68 0
3 30 1 F 2 L
4 31 1 B 2 F
4 31 1 F 44 0
;
run;

data long;
    set have;
    IndID=Ind1ID;
    Rel=Rel1;
    output;
    IndID=Ind2ID;
    Rel=Rel2;
    output;
    drop Ind1ID Ind2ID Rel1 Rel2;
run;

proc sort data=long nodupkey; by GroupID SubGID IndID Rel; run;

data want;
    set long;
    by GroupID SubGID IndID;
    if FIRST.IndID and LAST.IndID and Rel='F';
    drop Rel;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! Making a "long" database from the original solved the problem!